# with using angularjs framework is jade template engine obsolete

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, pug, mean-stack

I am new to MEAN stack/web/mobile development. If AngularJs can do all the client side templating/generating dynamic content, why do people still use Jade for server side templating?

To my incomplete knowledge it seemed Jade is somewhat obsolete. I know it may not be true. So my question is in what use case should one use Jade and what use case one should not use Jade? Is there a guideline for best practice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think Jade is obsolete. Take for example your application has to send a mail to users that create an account on your application. This mail would have their basic info etc. Jade would be very handy in such a case.

And using a templating system depends on the application itself. If one decides to not use a framework for their client side(like angularjs) you might wanna prefer using templating system to server side.